# Continuous CSS concatenation in background with Yeoman

Tags: css, build, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and I can't find a way to trigger the [CSS task](http://yeoman.io/commandline.html#build) upon file change.

I have a project structure like

```
\ app
  -----\ module1
        ------- style.css
  -----\ module2
        ------- style.css
  -----\ module3
        ------- style.css
  -----\ styles
        ------- main.css
```

and I'd like Yeoman to

- watch all the CSS files within the modules;
- trigger the CSS concat/minification task;
- overwrite `app/styles/main.css`.

Here's my `Gruntfile.js`:

```js
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
  'use strict';
  //
  // Grunt configuration:
  //
  // https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md
  //
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project configuration
    // ---------------------

    // specify an alternate install location for Bower
    bower: {
      dir: 'app/components'
    },

    // Coffee to JS compilation
    coffee: {
      compile: {
        files: {
          // 'app/scripts/*.js': 'app/scripts/**/*.coffee',
          // 'test/spec/*.js': 'test/spec/**/*.coffee'
        }
      }
    },

    // compile .scss/.sass to .css using Compass
    compass: {
      dist: {}
    },

    // default watch configuration
    watch: {
      reload: {
        files: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          'app/*.html',
          'app/styles/**/*.css',
          'app/scripts/**/*.js',
          'app/images/**/*',
          'app/app/**/*'
        ],
        tasks: 'css reload'
      }
    },

    // default lint configuration, change this to match your setup:
    // https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/task_lint.md#lint-built-in-task
    lint: {
      files: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        'app/scripts/**/*.js',
        'spec/**/*.js'
      ]
    },

    // specifying JSHint options and globals
    // https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/task_lint.md#specifying-jshint-options-and-globals
    jshint: {
      options: {
        curly: true,
        eqeqeq: true,
        immed: true,
        latedef: true,
        newcap: true,
        noarg: true,
        sub: true,
        undef: true,
        boss: true,
        eqnull: true,
        browser: true
      },
      globals: {
        angular: true
      }
    },

    // Build configuration
    // -------------------

    // the staging directory used during the process
    staging: 'temp',

    // final build output
    output: 'dist',

    mkdirs: {
      staging: 'app/'
    },

    // Below, all paths are relative to the staging directory, which is a copy
    // of the app/ directory. Any .gitignore, .ignore and .buildignore file
    // that might appear in the app/ tree are used to ignore these values
    // during the copy process.

    // concat css/**/*.css files, inline @import, output a single minified css
    css: {
      'app/styles/main.css': ['app/styles/*.css', 'app/app/**/*.css']
    },

    // renames JS/CSS to prepend a hash of their contents for easier
    // versioning
    rev: {
      js: 'scripts/**/*.js',
      css: 'styles/**/*.css',
      img: 'images/**'
    },

    // usemin handler should point to the file containing
    // the usemin blocks to be parsed
    'usemin-handler': {
      html: 'index.html'
    },

    // update references in HTML/CSS to revved files
    usemin: {
      html: ['**/*.html'],
      css: ['**/*.css']
    },

    // HTML minification
    html: {
      files: ['**/*.html']
    },

    // Optimizes JPGs and PNGs (with jpegtran & optipng)
    img: {
      dist: '<config:rev.img>'
    },

    // rjs configuration. You don't necessarily need to specify the typical
    // `path` configuration, the rjs task will parse these values from your
    // main module, using http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#mainConfigFile
    //
    // name / out / mainConfig file should be used. You can let it blank if
    // you're using usemin-handler to parse rjs config from markup (default
    // setup)
    rjs: {
      // no minification, is done by the min task
      optimize: 'none',
      baseUrl: './scripts',
      wrap: true
    }
  });

  // Alias the `test` task to run `testacular` instead
  grunt.registerTask('test', 'run the testacular test driver', function () {
    var done = this.async();
    require('child_process').exec('testacular start --single-run', function (err, stdout) {
      grunt.log.write(stdout);
      done(err);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried writing your own watch configuration yet?

Comment: Keep in mind that you only want concatenation and minification on build. When developing you only want compass to generate the CSS files. The default generator should implement,net this just fine. This is the template (if you copy something make sure to fix the yeoman placeholders https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/templates/common/Gruntfile.js )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am new to grunt, but what I did to write a custom watch task was this. First I registered a new task which included only the things I want to run while I am developing. I want my project to run against unminified js, for example. So I don't ask for the min or concat tasks to be executed. Just lint them, test them and rewrite the html for development mode using `grunt-targethtml`.

```
    grunt.registerTask('devel', 'lint qunit targethtml');
```

Then I replace the default `watch` configuration to run the `devel` task

```
    watch: {
        files: '<config:lint.files>',
        tasks: 'devel'
    }
```

This is using the file list as defined for the lint task but you should be able to replace this with

```
       files: ['app/**/*.css']
```